# my title and navigation won't line up on the same line

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5CQN.jpg)I am trying to place my name and my navigation link on the same line when my screen hit 768px but it would not line up after setting their display to inline block. can anyone help please and thank. This is my repository.  https://github.com/corry010/mobile-first-reponsive-project

tried using just inline as display. but it wouldn't work also played around with the code but can't figure it out.

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* max-width: 1000px; will change it later */
}

.name {
  float: left;
}

.main-nav {
  float: right;
}

.main-nav li {
  float: left;
}

.name,
.main-nav,
.navigation,
.main-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header class="main-header">
  <div class="container clearfix">
    <h1 id="top-page" class="name links"><a href="#top-page">Cornelis Etta</a></h1>

    <nav class="navigation">
      <ul class="main-nav links">
        <li><a href="#top-page">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#interest">interest</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </div>
</header>
```

My name and navigation should be on the same line in a 768 screen.

Comment: please share a snippet to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @NidhinJoseph i have added a picture of its behaviour

Comment: mate, you cannot put a GitHub link and expect people willing to help to clone that and then recommend a solution. I suggest you put a working example or a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to get people started.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and put it in the question itself instead.

Comment: @NidhinJoseph I have added a snippet of the area I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [flex layout](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp) to get items aligned side-by-side and the add `align-items: center;` to have items within a flexbox centred.

*Please add the media query when you integrate with your site.*

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.name {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.main-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header class="main-header">
  <div class="container clearfix">
    <h1 id="top-page" class="name links"><a href="#top-page">Cornelis Etta</a></h1>

    <nav class="navigation">
      <ul class="main-nav links">
        <li><a href="#top-page">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#interest">interest</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </div>
</header>
```